# How to create a storyboard and link it to an existing UIViewController?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm quite new to the Xamarin.iOS platform.

I created an empty Xamarin.iOS project then create my main UIViewController, which is **UIViewController1** and then set it up in the AppDelegate.cs:

```
            // If you have defined a root view controller, set it here:
            var view1 = new UIViewController1();
            Window.RootViewController = view1;

            // make the window visible
            Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

In the UIViewController1 I hard-code all the labels and buttons and stuff. Like this:

```
  var frame = new CGRect(10, 10, 300, 30);
                var Label = new UILabel(frame);
View.AddSubView(Label);
```

But now when everything is confirmed to be working correctly, I want to create a storyboard for my **UIViewController1** and move all of the elements onto it for future maintenance, so after creating an Empty Storyboard how can I link it to my current UIViewController1?

The other solutions that I found just don't work. All I got is a blank white screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your empty Storyboard, on the left window you will see the Toolbox(if you didn't see it, Ctrl + Alt + X to open it). Select a `ViewController` then put it on the Storyboard.

Here you will see a Storyboard with only one ViewController in it like:

[image]

Click the yellow button at left bottom of the ViewController. In the Property window we can choose its Class, click the down arrow to select:

[image]

In this way, we have bound the ViewController to the `UIViewController1`. But we also need to create a initial method in this class:

```
public UIViewController1 (IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
}
```

If you want to use the Storyboard as your initial Window, open your info.plist, select the Main Interface to your Storyboard. Then in the `FinishedLaunching()` remove all your code about initializing the `Window`:

```
//var view1 = new UIViewController1();
//Window.RootViewController = view1;
// make the window visible
//Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

Moreover instead of constructing the ViewController with `var view1 = new UIViewController1();`, we should use `UIStoryboard.FromName("StoryboardName", null).InstantiateViewController("ViewControllerID");`. This ViewControllerID can be set in the property window I post above called **Storyboard ID**;

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.